# What type of shelf support peg is this?

Tags: support, shelf

My kitchen cabinets have the support pegs shown in the photo below.  The one on top is the front peg and the one on the bottom is the rear.  The

[image: Front and Rear support pegs]

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ..... have you read what you wrote?

Comment: The op is asking the type how is that a shopping question? I agree with jsotola that it is unclear as the photos are also not very clear.

Comment: To be fully honest the photos are terrible.

Answer (score 1):

The back peg pins into a hole in the underside of the shelf, so that the shelf doesn't slide forward. You could replace it with a normal peg.

Comment: They are also pretty easy to find in the specialty hardware drawers in the fasteners isle of just about any hardware store.